# Probability Theory proof question

Tags: probability

> **Problem:**
>
> In football, a coin known to be unfair is tossed to see who receives the first kickoff. Your team has a peculiar curse in that the probability of winning the game given that they won the toss is exactly the same as the probability of losing the game given that they lost the toss. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the event that your team wins the toss and $W$ the event that your team wins the game. It may be assumed $0<\mathbb P(W) < 1$.
>
> Show that $W$ and $\mathcal C$ are independent *iff* $\mathbb P(W) = \frac 1 2$

Hi for this question I know how to prove $\mathbb P(W)=1/2$ if $W$ and $\mathcal C$ are independent. How to prove $W,\mathcal C$ are independent if $\mathbb P(W)=1/2$ ?

Thank you!

Comment: ==, That was not the question all about

Answer (score 1):

Approach that seemed to work for me, although I don't know if it's the fastest way there: we need to show $P(W) = P(W\mid\mathcal{C})$. We can write 
$$P(W)=P(W\mid\mathcal{C})P(\mathcal{C})+P(W\mid\mathcal{C}')P(\mathcal{C}').$$
We don't know $P(W\mid\mathcal{C})$; let's call it $\alpha$ (we want it to be $1/2$). We don't know $P(\mathcal{C})$; let's call it $\beta$ (and we know $\beta\neq1/2$).  Then the above gives us
$$1/2 = \alpha\beta + (1-\alpha)(1-\beta)$$
(the statement of the "curse" gives us $1-\alpha$). Solve for $\alpha$. (You will end up wanting to divide by $(1-2\beta)$ if all goes well, and since we know it's an unfair coin, that's legit.)

Comment: Thanks for the extraordinary work!

Comment: @tabstop why is $P(W|C') = 1 - P(W|C)$?

Comment: The "curse" says that the probability of winning the game, given winning the toss, is the same as the probability of losing the game, given losing the toss.  That means that $P(W\mid\mathcal{C})=P(W'\mid\mathcal{C}')$, and then taking the complement of the second one gets us what we want.

Comment: right, I forgot about the "curse". +1